# How can I represent the information in this DataFrame as a time series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
             start_time             end_time    user
0  2016-12-17 03:10:07   2016-12-17 03:18:10  andrew
1  2016-12-17 03:11:07   2016-12-17 03:15:07   eddie
2  2016-12-17 03:12:08   2016-12-17 03:19:08  andrew  
3  2016-12-17 03:13:08   2016-12-17 03:14:06   eddie
...
```

Each row represents a job that was submitted to a compute cluster. `start_time` is when to scheduled job started to run, and `end_time` is when it completed.

How can I create a new DataFrame indexed by time, which describes how many jobs each user had running at a given moment?

Comment: What time values should the new dataframe use for the index, the combination of all start/end times or some regular intervals?

Comment: Ideally I'll be able to do it both ways..

Answer (score 1):

This was a fairly interesting question.  You basically have two separate time series for each user.  The first step is to add a simple column that just indicates something happened (the columns `event`).  The strategy is to pivot the data such that the rows are the time, the columns are the users, and the events are the values.

To create a full time series, we then need to resample the time series (I used 1 second in this case) and fill in the missing values with 0 (since no event occurred.  The `.min().fillna(0)` is to fill the data frame with NAs then zeros, I think you can shortcut this using `apply(lambda x:...)`

```
df['event'] = 1
df_starts = df.pivot('start_time', 'user', 'event').fillna(0).resample('1S').min().fillna(0)
df_stops = df.pivot('end_time', 'user', 'event').fillna(0).resample('1S').min().fillna(0)
```

Next we create a full index from both new data frames, since the the indices have non-overlapping parts.  Then reindex both data frames using the new index.

```
full_index = df_starts.index.union(df_stops.index)

df_starts = df_starts.reindex(full_index, fill_value=0)
df_stops = df_stops.reindex(full_index, fill_value=0)
```

Finally, subtracting the stop events from the start events build a single data frame will all of the events.  Starts are positive 1s, stops are negative 1s.  Using `.cumsum()` gets the total running processes per user at any given time.

```
df_change = df_starts - df_stops
df_running = df_change.cumsum()
```

Here's a quick plot of `df_running`, x-axis is number of seconds since the first event.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is *a* solution. It might not be optimal but it seems to work pretty well. Of course I have generated my own data and assumed that the user starts with zero programs running.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

#Generate some data
m = 50
n = 2 * m

start_time = [dt.datetime(2016, 12, 17, 3, np.random.randint(0, 59)) for n in range(n)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'start_time': start_time,
                   'end_time': [date + dt.timedelta(0, np.random.randint(0, 3600)) for date in start_time],
                   'user': ['A', 'E'] * (m)})

#Doing the solution 
user_on = (df.ix[:, ['end_time', 'user']]
             .rename(columns={'end_time':'time'})
             .assign(on_off=-1))
user_off = (df.ix[:, ['start_time', 'user']]
              .rename(columns={'start_time':'time'})
              .assign(on_off=1))

df = pd.concat([user_on, user_off]).sort_values(by='time')
df = df.groupby(['time', 'user']).sum()
df = df.unstack().cumsum().fillna(method='ffill')
```

Here is an example of the tabular output.

```
                    on_off
              user  A   E
time        
2016-12-17 03:00:00 1   0
2016-12-17 03:01:00 2   1
2016-12-17 03:02:00 2   2
2016-12-17 03:03:00 4   4
2016-12-17 03:04:00 5   3
2016-12-17 03:06:00 7   4
```

To compare times this took **82ms** to do 10,000 samples including generating data.

Here is a graph showing the total number of programs running for a user over time (blue and green) and the change in running programs (ons - offs) at any given time (red and purple).

[image: Cusum vs Change in Programs run per User]

**Note:** In this scenario I am assuming that a user can start multiple programs in a given time stamp. This is only as a result of the how I am generating the test date.